# .Net Web API Add attribute in request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have created an web api in .net
I have custom authroization filter which check for token before executing the API method.

I want to add a custom attribute in custom authorization filter and get this attribute in every api method.

**Custom authorize**

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
 }
```

How to do this.

Thanks

Comment: this is using the .net framework rather than .netcore correct?

Comment: @JohnB This is .net framework

Comment: What type of parameter do you want to add? is it about user or request data ?

Comment: Like i want to add uid when I validating token in custom authorization class

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be well documented here: [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

Follow this guide and you can open a new question if you face any particular problem.

Comment: I don't have any issue with the authentication filter that is working fine, I have overridden the OnAuthorization method, I only want to add add an extra parameter somewhere which can be accessed in every api method

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding paramter in like below

```
Request.Properties.Add("test", "test");
```